# PHP File throwing 404 in the middle of executing (After ~45 seconds)

Tags: php, ajax, csv, runtime-error, http-status-code-404

I have a script in a folder that has no relevant execution time limits (I regularly run hour-long scripts from this directory) with a file in it. This file is called from an html form on a codeingiter view and uploads a csv file, reads it and updates database entries with the information contained within.

If I have a smaller csv file (1-1000 entries), it works fine. Anything over that will process about 1000 entries (including echoing debug text onto the screen) and THEN throw a 404 error.

I've since attempted to circumvent the error by making the post page make an ajax call but it does the exact same thing.

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - xxxx/xxxx/xxxxx.php"

I have confirmed that the script is running prior to the 404 by confirming changes in the database and seeing echo'd debug code on the screen.

Code that is executing when it throws the 404...
(in short, update id (first column) to have value (second column) from csv file.

```
if(file_exists($targetdir))
{
$file = fopen($targetdir, 'r');
$count = 0;
while(!feof($file))
{
    $x = (fgetcsv($file));
    if(is_numeric($x[1]) && $x[1] > 9999 && $x[0] != '-')
    {
        $count++;
        //  echo "UPDATE xxxx SET xxxxx ='".$x[0]."' WHERE id=".$x[1];
        $db->query("UPDATE xxxx SET xxxxx ='".$x[0]."' WHERE id=".$x[1]);
        //echo $x[1].' - '.$x[0]."<br/>";

    }
}
fclose($file);
}
```

**Edit**
It looks like Jquery is throwing the error? I googled around and saw people say it's a server setting (but not what server setting, so for the heck of it, I set the max execution time to 300s and have the same results).

xxxxx.php   404 xhr jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4  1.6 KB  40.07

[Image of 404 rendering after text is echo'd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHvQz.png)

Comment: I doubt it's the php code. you'd have to check the server config. a php script won't randomly throw out a 404 unless you explicitly tell it to. likely the server's terminating it for exceeding execution time limits, but why that'd show up as a 404 is... weird.

Comment: Do you hear the The Twilight Zone theme when this happens? Possibly the server is mis-configured, giving a 404 when it should send a 408?

Comment: I'm looking into it now, but it would throw a 408 in a short amount of time relative to some of the other scripts that run? I'm talking in one minute compared to some scripts that run for almost an hour without issue...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the setting that was tripping.
Rather than use the standard php max execution time, the timeout was getting hit from the FastCGI settings. Either from AJAX posting or from the read operation.

Either way, I increased FcgidIOTimeout in my apache settings on the server and was able to execute the full script.